# Regular Expressions - A word with only one capitalized letter and which doesn't contain numbers

Tags: regex

I am new to RegExp. I have a sentence and I would like to pull out a word which satisfies the following -

1. It must contain only one capitalized letter
2. It must consist of only characters/letters without numbers

For instance -
"appLe", "warDrobe", "hUsh"

The words that do not fit - "sf_dsfsdF", "331ffsF", "Leopard1997", "mister_Ram" et cetera.

How would you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should work:

- will find words that have **only one** capital letter
- will only find words with letters (no numbers or special characters)
- will match the **entire word**

```
\b(?=[A-Z])[A-Z][a-z]*\b|\b(?=[a-z])[a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]*\b
```

#### Matches:

```
appLe
hUsh
Harry
suSan
I
```

#### Rejects

```
HarrY     - has TWO capital letters
warDrobeD - has TWO capital letters
sf_dsfsdF - has SPECIAL characters
331ffsF   - has NUMBERS
Leopd1997 - has NUMBERS 
mistram   - does not have a CAPITAL LETTER
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/iMT1fk/1)

##### Note:

If the capital letter is OPTIONAL- then you will need to add a `?` after each `[A-Z]` like this:

```
\b(?=[A-Z])[A-Z]?[a-z]*\b|\b(?=[a-z])[a-z]+[A-Z]?[a-z]*\b
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How long have you been doing RegExp? I wonder how I could polish up my skills in this area?

Comment: I have been doing it for about a month now. Upskill by trying to answer questions on SO (try to work them out yourself before seeing the answer), and practice on regex101.com. Like everything, it just takes time and perseverance. As you see other alternative answers, you start to pick up some tricks for next time. I am still learning. Got a long way to go yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using character sets (`[a-z]` & `[A-Z]`) with appropriate quantifiers (use `?` for one or zero capitals), wrapped in `()` to capture, surrounded by word breaks `\b`.
If the capital is optional and can appear anywhere use:

```
/\b([a-z]*[A-Z]?[a-z]*)\b/   //will still match empty string check for length
```

If you always want one capital appearing anywhere use:

```
/\b([a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*)\b/    // does not match empty string
```

If you always want one capital that must not be the first or last character use:

```
/\b([a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+)\b/    // does not match empty string
```

Here is a working snippet demonstrating the second regex from above in JavaScript:

```js
const exp = /\b([a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*)\b/
const strings = ["appLe", "warDrobe", "hUsh", "sf_dsfsdF", "331ffsF", "Leopard1997", "mister_Ram", ""];

for (const str of strings) {
  console.log(str, exp.test(str))
}
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is great for dev & testing!

Answer (score 0):

**RegExp:**

```js
/\b[a-z\-]*[A-Z][a-z\-]*\b/g
```

**Demo:**

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/3jbiq0/1)

**Explanation**

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` \b[a-z\-]* ``` | Find a point where a non-word is adjacent to a word (`[A-Za-z0-9\-]` or `\w`), then match zero or more lowercase letters and hyphens (note, the hyphen needs to be escaped (`\-`)) |
| ``` [A-Z] ``` | Find a single uppercase letter |
| ``` [a-z\-]*\b ``` | Match zero or more lowercase letters and hyphens, then find a point where a non-word is adjacent to a word |